# Top Toolbar is overlapping status bar which is merged in UIImageview in iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

Top toolbar is overlapping status bar which is already merged in UIImageview.

Added this piece of code to viewdidload but not helping

```
float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (systemVersion >= 7.0) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Any ideas how this can be fixed.

Thanks